# Vue js keeping dropdown values when selection an other one

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

Hello i have a dropdown (Select of countries) and i want when i choose a country i get cities of this country in a new dropdown (total of dropdown now : 2) and when i select the second country i want get an other dropdown of cities of this country so i will have now 3 dropdowns in total.
My problem here is when i select a country and select a city my selection disapear after selecting an other country.
How can i resolve this?
I'm using multiselect in country dropdown and simple select in cities dropdown

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function() {
    return {
        selectedCountries: [],
        selectOptionsCountries: [
        { value: 3, name: 'FRANCE' },
        { value: 5, name: 'USA' },
        { value: 6, name: 'CANADA' },
        { value: 8, name: 'MOROCCO' }
      ],
      selectedCities: [],
      selectOptionsCities: []
    }
  },
  methods: {

  },
  watch: {
    selectedCountries: function(newValue, oldValue) {
      this.selectOptionsCities = [];
      this.selectedCities = [];

      for( var i = 0, length = newValue.length; i < length; i++ ){

        this.selectedCities[i] = [];

        if( newValue[i] === 3 ){
          this.selectOptionsCities.push(
            [{ value: 31, name: 'Paris' },
            { value: 32, name: 'Marseille' }]
          )
        }
        if( newValue[i] === 5 ){
          this.selectOptionsCities.push(
            [{ value: 51, name: 'New-York' },
            { value: 52, name: 'Boston' }]
          )
        }
        if( newValue[i] === 6 ){
          this.selectOptionsCities.push(
            [{ value: 61, name: 'Montreal' },
            { value: 62, name: 'Vancouver' },
            { value: 63, name: 'Ottawa' },
            { value: 64, name: 'Toronto' }]
          )
        }
        if( newValue[i] === 8 ){
          this.selectOptionsCities.push(
            [{ value: 81, name: 'Rabat' },
            { value: 82, name: 'Casablanca' },
            { value: 83, name: 'Fes' }]
          )
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```
<div id="app">

  Selected countries : {{ selectedCountries }}
  <br />
  Selected cities : {{ selectedCities }}
  <br />
  <select v-model="selectedCountries" multiple>
     <option v-for="(option, index) in selectOptionsCountries" :value='option.value'>
       {{ option.name }}
     </option>
  </select>

  <select v-for="(optionsCities, index) in selectOptionsCities" v-model="selectedCities[index]" multiple>
    <option v-for="(option, index) in optionsCities" :value='option.value'>
       {{ option.name }}
     </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue should generally be data driven. To that extent, I've modified your code to achieve your result. Here is the new data structure.

```
const countries = [
  { 
    value: 3, 
    name: 'FRANCE', 
    cities: [
      { value: 31, name: 'Paris' },
      { value: 32, name: 'Marseille' }
    ], 
    selectedCities: [] },
  { 
    value: 5, 
    name: 'USA', 
    cities: [
      { value: 51, name: 'New-York' },
      { value: 52, name: 'Boston' }
    ], 
    selectedCities: []},
  { 
    value: 6, 
    name: 'CANADA', 
    cities: [
      { value: 61, name: 'Montreal' },
      { value: 62, name: 'Vancouver' },
      { value: 63, name: 'Ottawa' },
      { value: 64, name: 'Toronto' }
    ], 
    selectedCities: [] 
  },
  { 
    value: 8, 
    name: 'MOROCCO', 
    cities:[
      { value: 81, name: 'Rabat' },
      { value: 82, name: 'Casablanca' },
      { value: 83, name: 'Fes' }
    ], 
    selectedCities: [] 
  }
]
```

And the code

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function() {
    return {
      countries,
      selectedCountries: []
    }
  }, 
  computed:{
    originalSelectedCountry(){
      return this.selectedCountries.map(country => country.value) 
    },
    originalSelectedCities(){
      return this.selectedCountries.reduce((acc, country) => {
        acc.push(country.selectedCities.map(city => city.value))
        return acc
      },[])
    }
  }
});
```

And here is the template

```
<div id="app">
  Selected countries : {{ originalSelectedCountry }}
  <br />
  Selected cities : {{ originalSelectedCities }}
  <br />
  <select v-model="selectedCountries" multiple >
     <option v-for="country in countries" :value='country' :key="country.value">
       {{ country.name }}
     </option>
  </select>
  <select v-for="country in selectedCountries" v-model="country.selectedCities"  :key="country.value" multiple>
    <option v-for="city in country.cities" :value="city">{{city.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Here is the working [example](http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/LWodEL?editors=1010).

Here are the significant points.

- I moved the cities associated with each country into the country's data. That way, building the select flows naturally and you don't have to watch the selected countries.
- Since you have multiple sets of selected cities, it doesn't make much sense to try to use one model for all the sets. I added a `selectedCities` property to each country.
- I turned your former `selectedCountries` and `selectedCities` into computed values. These values can just be derived from the current `selectedCountries` because `selectedCities` is a property of each country. In my opinion, `selectedCities` (which I turned into `originalSelectedCities`) is a fairly useless data structure. What happens if the order of your cities changes? Now you have no idea what countries the two dimensional arrays are associated with.

Comment: Thank you so much man for your replay, I get this error in console : [Vue warn]: Property or method "originalSelectedCountry" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.

Comment: @Codinga My example doesn't have that warning. Did you miss a piece of code?

Comment: No i miss nothing the console tell me that i must declare originalSelectedCountry in the data options, It's fixed by declaring computed vars after data, Now i get this error : TypeError: country.selectedCities.map is not a function :/

Comment: @Codinga `originalSelectedCountry` is a *computed* value, it does not need to be on data. Is there somewhere I can see what code you are working on? `selectedCities` needs to be initialized as an empty array in the data structure.

Comment: I get this error only when selecting city, This is my js code : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dvEKWX?editors=1010

Comment: @Codinga if I comment out the code that isn't from my pen in that, it works just fine so there is something missing somewhere. http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/bqyKPQ?editors=1010

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140109/discussion-between-codinga-and-bert-evans).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your model for the select box is doing what you are asking of it and clearing out when you set the selectedCities to and empty array.

You can simplify your code if you change the data structure a bit. Try this, see [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6dftnwcg/1/)

```
<div id="app" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      Selected countries : {{ selectedCountries }}
      <br />
      Selected cities : {{ selectedCities }}
      <br />
      <hr/>
      <select v-model="selectedCountries" 
         multiple class="form-control">>
        <option v-for="(option, index) in selectOptionsCountries" 
          :value='option.value'>
          {{ option.name }}
        </option>
      </select>
      <select v-model="selectedCities" multiple class="form-control">
        <!-- inline object literal -->
        <option v-bind:value="city.value" 
           v-for="(city, index) in selectOptionsCities"
           v-show="selectedCountries.indexOf(city.parent) > -1">
          {{ city.name }}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JavaScript.

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function() {
    return {
      selectedCountries: [],
      selectOptionsCountries: [
        { value: 3, name: 'FRANCE' },
        { value: 5, name: 'USA' },
        { value: 6, name: 'CANADA' },
        { value: 8, name: 'MOROCCO' }
      ],
      selectedCities: [],
      selectOptionsCities: [
        { value: 31, name: 'Paris', parent:3 },
        { value: 32, name: 'Marseille', parent:3 },
        { value: 51, name: 'New-York', parent:5 },
        { value: 52, name: 'Boston', parent:5 },
        { value: 61, name: 'Montreal', parent:5 },
        { value: 62, name: 'Vancouver', parent:6 },
        { value: 63, name: 'Ottawa', parent:6 },
        { value: 64, name: 'Toronto', parent:6 },
        { value: 81, name: 'Rabat', parent: 8 },
        { value: 82, name: 'Casablanca', parent: 8 },
        { value: 83, name: 'Fes', parent: 8 }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```